# React-Router: Force reload in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, amazon-cloudfront

We have a monolithic react SPA deployed with AWS Cloudfront. We are trying out microsite architecture where each route/path in the react app will be built and deployed as a standalone app. To achieve this we have configured path-based behaviors in Cloudfront to route the request to the respective origin which works fine.

Due to its SPA nature, all the routes defined in the monolithic react app tries to load pages without sending a request to the server. This is causing issues because we want a few routes to be loaded from the server so that CloudFront can route the requests properly.

How can we force react-router to load a specific route from the server?

`<Route exact path="/example" render={()=>console.log("load from server?");} />`

Comment: It looks like you are using `react-router-dom@5`. Can you share a more complete and comprehensive routing/navigation example of your router, routes, and routed components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `react-router` routing happens at client level, so you don't have to use it to get server-rendered pages.

What you need is just an `a` tag, like

```
<a href="/example" alt="A page you want to load">Label</a>
```

Comment: This is doable but I was thinking more along the lines of a catch-all solution. The idea is to slowly migrate all the routes from monolith to microsite so it would soon become a headache to update links every time we deploy a new microsite.

Comment: You can create a custom `Link` component and add kinda of a white list for external URL. When rendering it, you will decide if to use an internal (`react-router` link) or an external (`a` tag link) to redirect the user. You can use an `isExternal` property too, to avoid the white list inside the custom `Link` component. If that make sense to you I can edit my answer and add these considerations. You can progressively change the `isExternal` property once you move the route from client to server (or update the white list). If all your routes are already in an array, you can add it there.